# GLSL compute shader. Output varies if order of writes to SSBO changes

Tags: c, glsl

I observe very weird behaviour of my compute shader run.

The setup is usual. `SSBO` is mapped to a memory. Then follows a simple write to data.

```
for(uint i = 0; i < n; ++i){
 buf_pos = ...
 data[buf_pos] = 0xff00ff00;
}

return;
```

The above is fine and well. Some `uint`s get written to a buffer. The application reads it and read data goes as expected.

Now, the following is OK too. The data is filled with `uint`s.

```
data[0] = 0xff00ff00; /* single op */

for(uint i = 0; i < n; ++i){ /* multiple op */
 buf_pos = ...
 data[buf_pos] = 0xff00ff00;
}

return;
```

Though, if the order of "op"s is changed, only the last(single op) `uint` is written.

```
for(uint i = 0; i < n; ++i){ /* multiple op */
 buf_pos = ...
 data[buf_pos] = 0xff00ff00;
}

data[0] = 0xff00ff00; /* single op */

return;
```

I want all data to be written, so the `for` loop and the single write goes to buffer. How to get the desired behaviour?

**Update**

I check the buffer values with a simple print out of the buffer.

**Update**

It is an unpleasant situation. I can not reproduce this behaviour any more. **I am sure** that the code did the thing because I had found a remark with a code to repeat a bug. I had a few driver updates since the time, maybe that is the cause. Anyway, thank you for your time.

The **more code** was requested since I did the post... Well, the code still the same.

P.S More code and setup will be added to the question per request. Note that I do not get any errors in any of the above cases.

Comment: Not able to follow the question correctly. for(uint i = 0; i < n; ++i){
 buf_pos = ...
 data[buf_pos] = 0xff00ff00;
} >> in this for loop, code is looping for n times, but not seeing "i" is used. not sure what you are trying to achieve here on "data" ?,is code trying to write "0xff00ff00" in to first "n" entries of "data" ?.

Comment: does it also happen if you if `buf_pos = i;`?

Comment: Are you sure that `buf_pos` is ever `0`?

Comment: @NishadCM @tstanisl I had a code somewhere that does this. As I recall, `buf_pos` is calculated based on `i`. I think I did check for `buf_pos = i` case, I will update after I find this case.

Comment: could you provide more code?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Updated the question. Can not repeat the fault behaviour of a code. **BTW do you think I should close the question?**

Comment: could be that you were compiling and executing your code without having saved the file, hence your displayed code doesnt match the one compiled

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Yeah, it could be. Maybe some bits differ, the above is a complete code.